# How to change key size in OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh

How to change key size in OpenSSH? I would like to change it from 1024 key size length to 512.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure [this](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/10/05/ssh-keygen-tutorial-generating-rsa-and-dsa-keys/) is what you are after. You need to use ssh-keygen.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 512
```

this should create a 512 rsa crypto key

Comment: This doesn't work. OpenSSH back at least to 5.3 ~ 2009 requires minimum 768 bits for RSA, and the page you linked dated 2007 says the same. As an update, since 7.6 in 2017 the minimum is 1024. And of course RSA-512 was _broken_ and insecure since about 1990, although this Q did not ask about security. OpenSSL has always been, and even 1.1.1 in 2018 still is, willing to generate RSA-512 with `openssl genrsa 512`. c

Answer (score -2):

There's also a ServerKeyBits option in sshd_config, can set that to a minimum of 512.

Comment: That's only used for legacy SSH-1 connections, and is not used with SSH-2.